# Is this a variation of the decorator pattern or a pattern at all?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Below is a simplified version of code I've written to override a class method (using composition), in this case method name i'm overriding is addbuttons(); The class "Screen" adds buttons to a screen whereas class "SubScreen" adds custom buttons to an instance of Screen. Maybe this is not an example of decorator pattern since I'm overriding functionality instead of extending it ? Is there a better way (using a design pattern ?) to achieve same functionality ?

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        AddComponents add1 = new Screen();
        add1.addButtons();

        Screen newScreen = new Screen();
        AddComponents add2 = new SubScreen(newScreen);
        add2.addButtons();
    }

}
    public interface AddComponents {

         public void addButtons();
        }

public class Screen implements AddComponents{

    public void addButtons() {
        //Add Buttons to screen class
    }

}
public class SubScreen implements AddComponents{

    private Screen screen;

    public SubScreen(Screen screen){
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public void addButtons() {
        //add different custom buttons to Screen class
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility would be to call it *Proxy*. *Decorator* and *Proxy* are technically very similar - the difference is - in most cases - not a technical one but based on the intention.
Your example is a little bit minimal and therefore it is hard to guess the intention correctly.

**Edit**

At the detailed level: `Screen` and `SubScreen` do not share any code. If you start adding methods to both implementations and the common interface `AddComponents` you might find

- that you must duplicate code both in `Screen` and `SubScreen` (or delegate to `Screen`) and
- that you must add methods to `AddComponents` which make this interface badly named.

If both screen classes are similar both on the abstract logical level *and* at the implementation level, then a an class `AbstractScreen` with two derived classed would be better. To bring back pattern speak: Use a *Factory Method* in `AbstractScreen` to specialize the behaviour regarding the different buttons.

On your current code there is one strange thing: Why is there a method `addButton` defined anyway? Simply add the buttons in the appropriate constructor, since the user has to call `addButtons` in any case and the method does not have arguments.

Another point not explained is this: `SubScreen` has a reference to `Screen` which is not used. Why? Will there be more method in all involved classes `Screen`, `SubScreen` and `AddComponents`? Will each method be a in `SubScreen` delegate to `Screen` or only half of them?

You see - there are many possibilities we do not know and are not shown in the example code but are very important. I'm sure that your head contains a lot of details saying "This proposed stuff will not work because I want to do this and that one way or the other in the near future." Sadly we cannot get the content of your head into this site without more writing. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I just read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern and now seems to me to be Proxy. My intention is to add different buttons to same GUI screen depending on menu item a user selects, does this suffice ?

Comment: You describe the intention of the code as seen from the outside - the "**What** shall this code achive?" intention. But design patterns like _Decorator_ don't exist on this level. I was aiming at the "**How** does the code implement this goal?" intention. On this level the mentioned design pattern are important.

Comment: Is the intention not described in the code I posted in the question? Can you give me an example of what you mean by "intention" ?

Comment: FYI: I edited _twice_ and tried to explain what i mean with the **How** intention.

Comment: "Another point not explained is this: SubScreen has a reference to Screen which is not used. Why? Will there be more method in all involved classes Screen, SubScreen and AddComponents? Will each method be a in SubScreen delegate to Screen or only half of them?" In actuality the reference to Screen is used, the button components are added to the screen instance. There should'nt be more methods in involved classes. I did'nt consider your points but they have been of much use.Is there documentation on how to derive "intentions" when choosing a design pattern or does it just come with experience?

Comment: *The* standard book _[Design Patterns][http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29]_ *is* the standard book, *because* it not only describes the patterns on a technical level, it also explains each pattern from _various_ semitechnical viewpoints in great detail.